# Loading external page template and enqueue script from plugin causes 403 forbidden error

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, errors, wp-enqueue-script

I have a plugin, which creates a panel on following page:

```
mysite.com/wp-content/plugins/myplugin/includes/mypanel.php
```

I want to use this panel on following page

```
mysite.com/mypanel
```

Solution that I tried was to using `mypanel.php` as page template as below:

```
add_filter( 'page_template', 'wpa3396_page_template' );
function wpa3396_page_template( $page_template )
{
    if ( is_page( 'mypanel' ) ) {
        $page_template = dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/includes/mypanel.php';
    }
    return $page_template;
}
```

This way the page displays but none of the javascript works. So I have tried to import plugin's javascript in functions php.

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','Load_Template_Scripts_wpa83855');
function Load_Template_Scripts_wpa83855(){

    if ( strpos(get_page_template(), 'mypanel.php') !== false ) {
        wp_enqueue_script('wtd', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/wp-content/plugins/myplugin/js/wtd.js');
    }

}
```

Which resulted 403 forbidden error. I added tried adding an .htaccess folder into plugin's page but it continued to give error.

Please tell me what is the correct way to solve this problem.

**EDIT:** 
After some answers below (thanks everyone). I moved my codes to my plugin's page, and no more 403 forbidden error. But my buttons are not working, and I feel like my js file not run over the page.

My js file starts with: `jQuery(document).ready(function()`

Here final code on plugin's page:

```
/* Make tisort-tasarla page as template */
add_filter( 'page_template', 'wpa3396_page_template' );
function wpa3396_page_template( $page_template )
{
    if ( is_page( 'tisort-tasarla' ) ) {
        $page_template = dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/includes/tshirt-designer-design-template.php';
    }
    return $page_template;
}
/* Add Javascript to T-Shirt Design Page */

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','Load_Template_Scripts_wpa83855');
function Load_Template_Scripts_wpa83855(){

    if ( is_page( 'tisort-tasarla' ) ) {
        wp_enqueue_script( 'wtd', plugins_url( '/js/wtd.js' , __FILE__ ), array( 'jquery' ));        
    }    
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that your server is not blocking access to your script through `.htaccess` file? Also try using `plugins url()` to get the path to your plugins directory and see if it helps.

Comment: Hi, why do you think plugins_url will work? It just returns the path as string isn't it ? @JackJohansson , I tried the following solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37559573/1235655

Comment: Hi. The absolute path and URL are differently approached by server. As you can see, there are already 2 answers for your question based on my comment, so i suggest you give it a try, and update the question with the output results.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your CODE is fine, the reason you are getting 403 error is because `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` returns absolute PATH to your web root, not URL.

JavaScript needs to be added as URL. So, you may use `Load_Template_Scripts_wpa83855` function in your plugin and then use:

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'wtd', plugins_url( '/js/wtd.js' , __FILE__ ) );
```

CODE to add JavaScript.

> ***Note:*** obviously you can make the CODE even better using logic like what [@nathan used in his answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/262190/110572), i.e. adding:
>
> `add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','Load_Template_Scripts_wpa83855');`
>
> within the `wpa3396_page_template()` function in `if ( is_page( 'mypanel' ) ) {}` condition block; but that's not the reason of the error. Server PATH cannot be accessed by browser, that's why the server returns `Access Forbidden` error.

### Full CODE (Updated):

Here is the full CODE for your convenience (add it in your main plugin file):

```
add_filter( 'page_template', 'wpse_262042_page_template' );
function wpse_262042_page_template( $page_template ) {
    if( is_page( 'mypanel' ) ) {
        add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpse_262042_enqueue_scripts' );
        $page_template = plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'includes/mypanel.php';
    }
    return $page_template;
}

function wpse_262042_enqueue_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'wtd', plugins_url( 'js/wtd.js' , __FILE__ ), array( 'jquery' ) );
}
```

Comment: 403 error is gone but nothing happened, buttons doesn't work, my js file starts like this: jQuery(document).ready(function()... does it mean it won't work if I add it manually afterwards? How can I overcome this ?

Comment: You must also make your script load after jQuery. You may do so using:
`wp_enqueue_script( 'wtd', plugins_url( '/js/wtd.js' , __FILE__ ), array( 'jquery' ) );`.  This CODE tells WordPress to load your script after jQuery. Also, `plugins_url()` function will not work in your theme's `functions.php` file, add that CODE in your main plugin file, as I've said before.

Comment: I used as you mentioned but it did not affect, can you please check the EDIT I made to my question at the bottom If I am not missing something? @Fayaz

Comment: Your CODE should work if: **(1)** you have all the files & CODE in the proper places **(2)** There is no error in your JavaScript (check in console & view source if JS file is loading) **(3)** your `/includes/tshirt-designer-design-template.php` template file has call to `wp_head()` WordPress function just before the HTML ending `</head>` tag & `wp_footer()` call just before ending `</body>` tag. Without these two functions header and footer scripts & styles will not load.

Answer (score 1):

If you already have, or are planning to have, a page called 'mypanel', then you can use the `page_template` filter to filter the template used on that page. I'm assuming that's what you're doing.

We can use the `page_template` filter to use a custom template for this page. While using this filter, we can add an action to enqueue scripts specific for this page.

```
add_filter( 'page_template', 'wpse_262042_page_template', 10, 1 );
function wpse_262042_page_template( $page_template ) {
  if( is_page( 'mypanel' ) ) {
    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpse_262042_enqueue_scripts' );
    $page_template = plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'includes/mypanel.php';
  }
  return $page_template;
}
function wpse_262042_enqueue_scripts() {
  wp_enqueue_script( 'wpse-262042', plugins_url( '/js/wpse-262042.js', __FILE__ ) );
}
```

In the `/includes/mypanel.php` template file, make sure to call `wp_head()` and `wp_footer()` otherwise the enqueued scripts won't be printed.

Comment: Please fix your CODE, `$page_template` must be path, not URL.